# How do you goto the end of line in vim after using a hotkey?

Tags: linux, vim, macros, timestamp

I'm trying to insert a timestamp and move the cursor to the end of the line while remaining in insert mode. Currently what I have prints the time and exits insert mode, AND the cursor stays at the beginning of the timestamp.

```
map <F3> :r! date "+\%H:\%M:\%S -- "<CR>
```

Cursor stays at the 2:

```
21:07:35 -- 
^
```

I want it here:

```
21:07:35 --  
            ^
```

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not general computing issues. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Answer (score -1):

map `<F3`> :r! date "+%H:%M:%S -- "A

the addition of A did it